# Woocommerce updater removal

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried the following function to get rid of the updater removal but it just won't go away.

```
/*********************************************************************************************/
/********************************** Remove WooCommerce Updater  *******************************/
/*********************************************************************************************/

remove_action('admin_notices', 'woothemes_updater_notice');
```

I also tried this:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: My Admin Theme
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: My WordPress Admin Theme - Upload and Activate.
Author: Ms. WordPress
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://example.com
*/

function my_admin_theme_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-admin-theme', plugins_url('wp-admin.css', __FILE__));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_theme_style');
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_theme_style');

?>
```

With CSS attached to it:

```
.updated.fade {display:none;}
```

NOTHING WORKS. Any "geniuses" out there?

Answer (score 0):

here is your magic trick (does not require plugin, can be in themes functions.php):

```
function removewoo_updates_info( $value ) {
   unset( $value->response['woocommerce/woocommerce.php'] );
   return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'removewoo_updates_info' );
```

But be careful, updates are necessary ;)

Comment: Now this is what I get after adding your code to my functions.php  [link] http://postimg.org/image/w043eo76v/ [link]

Comment: Which ver. of wp & wooc. are you running?

Comment: WC Version:  2.0.20
WC Database Version:  2.0.5
WP Version:  WP 3.8.1
Web Server Info:  Apache
PHP Version:  5.3.24

Comment: Was tested by me on wp 3.8.1 and wc 2.0.20 and works perfect. But as I can see on a screenshoot, this is not woocommerce updater info, it's wooThemes, look in theme folder for that string "install..".

Comment: Or if it is themes plugin modify function I posted by changing the path.

Comment: "install..".?!!! I am not clear what I am suppose to look for in my themefolder. I am using the retailer theme. Thanks a lot Michal for your help...If there is any function I can try hit me....

Comment: Inspecting elements provides me with this CSS code: `DIV#message.updated.woocommerce-message.wc-connect`

Comment: Stackoverflow is not allowing disscusions. Will add to my answer code for blocking theme updater tomorow.

Comment: I fixed it by CSS=>inspect element and added: Display:none; Thanks!